# Spring boot custom logger log4j2

Tags: logging, spring-boot, log4j2, classnotfound

I have a simple spring boot JAR application, which uses a custom logging library. ( An extension on top of log4j2 ). 
The log4j2.xml element Configuration has the name of the "package" where the appender can be found.

This custom logging library works  fine with other .war,.jar files and other standalone java implementations other than spring boot.

As spring boot documentation says, i had added the log4j2.xml to its class path and when I run it on eclipse IDE it works as expected.

However when i try to build the jar using, the uber jar it finds the log4j2.xml but fails to find the custom logging library, even though the jar is in the lib folder of the finally packaged jar.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I checked the sequence of classloading that happens between uber jar and eclipse ide, and the difference is clear  uber jar just loads the core log4j library and starts reading the XML even before the the custom appender is loaded. So the classnotfound exception and no logging.

While eclipse loads everything in the lib folder.

I moved the appender code from the logging jar to my spring boot project, it works. bundling the appender into a jar and referring it through POM doesn't work.

Also we are using the JarLauncher configuration, which should ideally load everything from the lib folder.

Here is the closest link I got to the same problem,

http://www.widecodes.com/CJVVWXXgkq/how-to-create-custom-appender-for-log4j2-in-spring.html

But looks like the developer had the appender in his workspace rather than a jar. :-(. Which works for me.

I am new to springboot, how do i make the logging work? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the solution, the problem was not with spring boot, but with the way the custom logging api was built. it was built with -proc:none compiler argument, which dint allow the log4j annotations to be built. log4j2 annotations when built creates a log4j2Plugin.dat which was missing.

While log4j2 documentation does not elaborate on that part much, it was stackoverflow which had users talk about the .dat file.

Once the argument was removed from the custom logging component and was built, and the spring boot project was built with newly built logging component , spring boot was able to find the appender and load it.

Not sure why  mvn spring-boot:run let it work, ( understandable eclipse did )  but not java -jar. Also this custom appender has worked with other war/stand alone jar applications and why does spring boot alone has to have a problem with it. I take it, it is the classloader which works different.